# How to impose power constraint on an encoder's output while training a deep NN?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-power, deep-learning

A deep encoder which takes in a 4 bit input gives out an 8-dimensional vector. If I want the power of this 8-D vector constrained to be 1, then I should  multiply all the elements by A/B? Where A is sqrt(8) and B is Sum of squares of elements.

Comment: You can normalize the power of a vector `v` as `v'=v / ||v||` where `||v||=sqrt(sum(v_i^2))`. Now the normalized vector has a power of 1.